# Map Collection<String> to String column

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

How do I map `Collection<String>` into `String` column using Hibernate?

I have a class which has multiple collections that only have a few elements.
So it would be overkill to create multiple mapping tables. What is the best way to create hibernate mapping in this case?

```
public class MyClass {
   private Collection<String> names;
   private Collection<String> nickNames;
   .
   . //more collections have only few (1-2) elements
   // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save every collection as a one to many mapping. Otherwise you are breaching database normalization [Click](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms)